# Is there a similar method to the `didEncounterError` from ApolloServer that I can use in GraphQL Yoga?

Tags: javascript, gql, graphql-yoga, yoga-x1

I'm migrating from ApolloServer to GraphQL Yoga server, and in the plugins of ApolloServer, they have the `didEncounterError` method which gives you access to the context, and I couldn't find something similar in the documentation of Yoga, does anyone have an idea how can I access the context when an error occurs?

This is what I had on ApolloServer

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
...,
plugins: [
    {
      requestDidStart() {
        return {
          didEncounterErrors(context) {
            context.errors.forEach(error => {
              console.log(context.operationName);
              console.log(error);
             }
          });
        };
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useLogger` plugin from `graphql-yoga` like this:

```
plugins: [
  useLogger({
    logFn: (eventName, args) => {
      args.result.errors.forEach((error) => {
        console.log(args.operationName);
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
  }),
],
```